Motion in the Ocean
This is part 65 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.


”It’s not the size of the crossword that counts.” – unknown

Dear Puzzling,
Today I have dived into the crystal clear waters of a tropical island group known for its diverse flora and fauna. I have seen sea turtles playing among colourful corals, and watched massive whale sharks and manta rays swim majestically by. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Nonogram on Penpa+
Mini-crosswords on Penpa+
Top left, across
2. Ancient string instrument
5. Performed again
7. British rule of India
9. Wintertime virus
10. Rich amateurs at the poker table
11. Jacuzzis
Top left, down
1. Quiver contents
2. Its use is obligatory in some dog parks
3. Hundred Acre Wood inhabitant whose name rhymes with Pooh
4. Perplex
6. The other Dr Crane
8. 400 metres, on many tracks
Top right, across
14. A type of figure skating jump
17. Japanese garment
18/34d. Animated film featuring a woolly mammoth
21. Colourful Japanese fish
22. One may cut you off
23. Heed
Top right, down
12. Card game from the makers of Uno
13. Hair parasites
15. "Exclusive" logic port
16. Affectionate
19. Wild swine
20. 0.01 kronor
Bottom left, across
24. Find not guilty
28. Sterilize
29. Web portal with once-popular Instant Messenger
33. Rower's tool
35. Shade of blue
36. Answered (the door)
Bottom left, down
24. Someplace 43 down
25. Big kahuna
26. At most
27. Scottish form of John
30. How many "unplugged" albums are recorded
31. Produced offspring
32. Shock
34. (See 18 across)
Bottom right, across
39. Miniature circus performer
41. Wax pencil
42. Challenge that can be "double dog"
46. — Korbut, Soviet gymnast
48. Stonemason's tool
49. Alexander or Francis
Bottom right, down
37. Australian rockers
38. A long time
39. Southernmost city in Portugal
40. A long time
43. "What — is new?"
44. Simba's mate
45. Global disease control experts
47. Hair product

Gladys will return in 66: Luftballons.

SOLVER NOTE: I do not have a full logical path for the nonogram as I solved it for at least three hours, failed two times, and now I'm a bit tired to backtrack and find out the full path. I will be offering a 400-point bounty to anyone who can provide it.
With that said, Gladys went to

 Baa Atoll, in the Maldives!

The finished crossword:

 

The finished nonogram:

 


 While I do not have a full logical path, I can say for sure that the third row and fifth column (highlighted in red) are good starting points, because they can only be filled in one way.

 The arrows and the nonogram image formed show a maze that needs to be solved.

Doing that

 and overlaying the maze path on the nonogram + crossword template, we have:




 Following the path again, we get the string BERYL ALEX ALICE ABBY TONYA OLIVE LESLEY LEANN, which can all be girls' names. But we focus on each of their first letters, which spell out the answer.

